# PHP Global Variables Issue

Tags: php, variables, scope, global

I've got a scope problem here. and no idea why its not working, ive got a setup as follows:

functions.php

```
global $id;
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

index.php

```
require_once('functions.php');
echo $id;
```

now inside functions.php i can echo out $id. however my echo $id; inside index.php is bringing up blank. absolutely nothing.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Since I don't see any functions or classes, everything is happening in the global scope anyway. File includes don't matter.

Comment: wonder why its returning blank then :s odd

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('error_display', true);`

Comment: @Owen: I hate to ask, but is $_GET['id'] being set? Have you tried assigning $id a static value like 42?

Comment: sort of not! id been using $.get and had pushed the variable of project instead of id. so in the URL bar it said ID but jquery had actually sent project sooooo its working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need globals between files, only for functions.

Functions.php

```
<?php
$foobar = "Hello";
?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
include('Functions.php');
echo $foobar;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, the `global` keyword allows you to reference variables in the global scope from inside a local scope - eg to access a global variable inside a function.  You don't need `global` in your example, because you are in the global scope anyway.

I suspect you are showing us a simplified version of what you have, where the issue is in code you haven't shown us.

**Why you shouldn't use globals**

Confusion like this is part of why using globals is a bad idea and should be avoided.

The alternative is to pass variables around explicitly, so for example if you call a function or instantiate a class from another file, you pass the variable in as a parameter to that function or constructor.  Doing this, instead of using global variables, makes it easier to follow what function is accessing what variable because you can follow the trail easier.

Comment: You asked "what am i doing wrong?".  I don't know see how this isn't an answer to that question.

Comment: maybe, but the fact it was a global wouldnt break it. which was my issue.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is why I suspect that the problem of `$_GET['id']` being empty is caused by something outside of the code you have shown us.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use globals, but you have it backwards. You declare the variable global after you include its definition:

file1.php:

```
$name = 'Josh';
```

file2.php:

```
require_once('file1.php');

global $name;

echo $name;
```

Comment: i know this, i just dont know why im getting blank result

Answer (score 0):

@thomasrutter is correct (+1) Global variables are`A Bad Thing`. Always seek alternatives.

Perhaps you can use $_SESSION (which sort of amounts to the same thing, I know), or declare a class which has a [static variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and use a getter() and setter() ?  (the latter uis definitely cleaner, but $_SESSION might tie in better with your design, I can't say)

Btw, I hope that `functions.php` was just an example name, or that you have an extermely simple project.

Otherwise `fucntions.ph`p is going to get extermaly large and hard to oversee. If you are going OO then user one file per class, otherwse try to group your functions into separate files (`file_management.php`, `databse.php`, `forms.php` and the like).

If you are just starting out, I would advise you to use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) and document your code with [PhpDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) comments which will allow you to generate good documentation which you can view in your browser (including the structure of your coed, what gets declared where, used where, descruptions of function parameters and return values, etc)

Btw, I notice that you use `include()` I prefer `require_once`. The `_once` helps spee dperformnce a little and hte `require` makes sure that you are aware of missing files more quickly.

Oh, and learn to use Xdebug,  which [plays well with NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html).